# which jboss application server works with netbeans 6.91.?

Tags: jboss, netbeans-6.9, installation, appserver

I am trying to add a jboss server in netbeans 6.9.1
I tried,
openlogic-jboss-5.1.0.GA-all-bin-1
jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final
jboss-as-distribution-6.0.0.20100721-M4-src
jboss-5.1.0.GA-src.tar
but it gives the same error select valid jboss application server 4 or 5
can anybody please give me a link with exact verson of it.
I need to specify the path to the folder of the server only or do i need to do anything else?
please explain in brief. 
Thank you.

your answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I am not deleting this question because anybody with such query can get help from it.

refer this link
http://www.paulomotta.pro.br/2011/05/14/netbeans-6-9-jboss-6-support-to-use-icefaces-2-0

download the code specified at the end of the block and put the files in the specified location.